# Qual a diferença entre as funções LOCATE e INSTR?

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

A descrição da função `LOCATE`, em tradução livre, é: Retorna a posição da primeira ocorrência de substring.

A descrição da função `INSTR`, em tradução livre, é: Retorna o índice da primeira ocorrência de substring.

Aparentemente fazem a mesma coisa, mesmo que com assinaturas e parâmetros levemente diferentes, porém não me parece que os desenvolvedores liberariam duas funções com funcionamento igual. Então fica a pergunta:

**Qual a diferença entre as funções [`LOCATE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_locate) e [`INSTR`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_instr) do MySQL?** E caso haja alguma, em que casos devo usar?

Comment: Em `INSTR` há: *This is the same as the two-argument form of LOCATE(), except that the order of the arguments is reversed*. Parecem ser iguais.

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss é muito bizarro ter duas funções iguais hahahaha

Comment: Concordo. Também estou procurando algo que justifique a existência das duas.

Comment: Fiz os testes desta [resposta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22171511/1452488) e também obtive tempos praticamente iguais, então provavelmente uma não é uma versão otimizada da outra.

Comment: Você não quer escrever uma resposta com as suas conclusões?

Comment: Enquanto não achar nada conclusivo, acho que não vale a pena.

Comment: Aparentemente eles primeiro criaram a `INSTR` (uma abreviação de "In String"), depois quiseram evoluir permitindo passar um terceiro argumento indicando a partir de qual posição iniciar a busca, e criaram outro método. Eles poderiam simplesmente ter modificado o original `INSTR` com o terceiro argumento opcional (o que não afetaria as chamadas já existentes), mas talvez eles queriam dar um nome mais intuitivo (mais fácil de lembrar). Até a forma como os métodos tratam a busca **case-sensitive** é igual, pode até ser que um internamente chama o outro, **já que não há** diferença na performance.

Comment: Mas a descrição dos dois métodos [no site do mysql](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html) pode levar alguém a se enganar. Um diz que retorna a posição, o outro diz que retorna o índice. Posição e índice são coisas diferentes. Por posição, eu de cara entenderia que começa em 1, ou zero caso não encontre. Já por índice, eu entenderia que começaria em zero, ou -1 caso não encontrasse.  Entretanto, ambos métodos possuem *o mesmo* comportamento.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No MySQL existem 3 maneiras retornar a primeira ocorrência de uma substring em uma string:

```
LOCATE(substr,str), LOCATE(substr,str,pos)
INSTR(str,substr)
POSITION(substr IN str)
```

Além de LOCATE permitir o parâmetro de posição de inicio da busca, segundo [Beginning MySQL Database Design and Optimization: From Novice to Professional](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=bu5n185SS4cC&pg=PA208&lpg=PA208&dq=WHY%20MYSQL%20LOCATE%20COMPATIBILITY&source=bl&ots=h9XzDRtAod&sig=kaYFBYzpvqUTuc1wRp2k4OcmuNk&hl=pt-BR&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiUxZ351IPUAhXDxlQKHUrxCEkQ6AEISTAF#v=onepage&q=WHY%20MYSQL%20LOCATE%20COMPATIBILITY&f=false) (Chad Russell,Jon Stephens, 2004, p. 208):

> POSITION() is standard SQL, LOCATE() is specific to MySQL(), INSTR() is
>   supported for compatibility with ORACLE.

Ou seja: POSITION() seria o mysql padrão, LOCATE() a função nativa do MySQL() e INSTR() estaria presente para manter compatibilidade com bancos ORACLE.

E tudo indica que elas tem a mesma implementação, já que Item_func_instr extende a classe Item_func_locate dentro do código fonte do MySQL em sql/item_func.h:

```
class Item_func_instr : public Item_func_locate
{
public:
  Item_func_instr(const POS &pos, Item *a, Item *b) :Item_func_locate(pos, a, b)
  {}

  const char *func_name() const { return "instr"; }
};
```

É importante observar que no manual do MySQL, POSITION(substr IN str) aparece como sinonimo de LOCATE(substr, str). Já com INSTR e LOCATE, apesar da descrição da função ser a mesma para o formato INSTR(str, substr) vs LOCATE (substr, str) não há menções sobre a implementação.

Answer (score 7):

A diferença é que no LOCATE você pode informar a partir de qual posição você quer achar a substring na string. Exemplo:

`INSTR('she sells seashells', 's') -> RETORNA 1`

`LOCATE('s', 'she sells seashells', 3) -> RETORNA 5`

`LOCATE('s', 'she sells seashells', 6) -> RETORNA 9`

`LOCATE('s', 'she sells seashells', 15) -> RETORNA 19`

Answer (score 4):

Locale aceita um terceiro parametro, este é para informar a partir de qual posição voce quer achar o termo na string

```
Mysql> SELECT LOCATE('bar', 'foobarbar');
        -> 4
Mysql> SELECT LOCATE('xbar', 'foobar');
        -> 0
Mysql> SELECT LOCATE('bar', 'foobarbar', 5);
        -> 7
```

Fonte:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_locate

Comment: Poderia explicar os casos `->4` e `->7` ?